# How to adjust x ticks to string values in Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, time-series

I have an issue plotting a very simple time series figure on Python. I've been playing with Twitter data and my x is days and times, while my y is some score I'm computing based on tweets. The obvious problem is that my x keeps on expanding to the extend that the x axis, when plotted, does not represent all the values of x in my data set. I'm completely fine with that, to be sure, but what I'd want is for the x axis to at least start with the first x value and end with the last x value in my dataset, so that I can assess the evolution of that score in near real time. That would at least create a graph where we can see how much the score I'm computing has evolved since I started collecting tweets, and until the latest day for which I'm plotting the score in question. Here's the code I have so far:

```
n = datetime.date.today().strftime("%B %d, %Y") #Here I'm registering today's date

a_plot=df_US.plot(x='Some timeframe', y='Some Score')
a_plot

plt.xticks(rotation=60)
plt.ylabel('Some Score')
plt.title('Evolution of Some Score in Tweets',fontdict=None, loc='center')
plt.savefig('Some Score('+n+').png', dpi=300, bbox_inches = 'tight')
plt.show()
```

That's what I get based on this script. 
 [Some Time Series Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZcBM.png)

I'm fine with the x axis starting where it does, only I'd like it to end for the latest value of x in the dataset. I'm also fine with there being less ticks in between.

I scoured the web for an answer to this issue but unfortunately I only find answers for integer values or for a finite number of strings. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iiuc, you could try the following function, which calculates n equidistant datetimes between the first and the last one of a given array:

```
import datetime

def custom_ticks(timings, n):
    dt = (timings[-1] - timings[0]).days +1
    return [timings[0]+i*datetime.timedelta(dt/(n-1)) for i in range(n)]
```

and then after plotting your dataframe, you can use this function to define your custom ticks:

```
plt.xticks(custom_ticks(df_US['Some timeframe'], 5))
```